# Mounting a USB drive on a synology system: "operation permitted for root only" although sudo was used

Tags: mount, sudo, usb, synology

I want to mount a USB drive on my NAS synology

Following those tutorials:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/37767/how-to-access-a-usb-flash-drive-from-the-terminal
https://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux

I could find the USB drive with the command:

```
$ blkid
/dev/mapper/vg1-volume_1: LABEL="2023.09.25-14:35:10 v64570" UUID="850bcccd-3982-43be-8857-ebd535c7ac92" UUID_SUB="998554af-d7c7-42de-b7fe-e0e153197119" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/md0: LABEL="1.44.1-64570" UUID="da99711c-d604-4e26-ae5b-27d549704693" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdq1: LABEL="Samsung USB" UUID="64A5-F009" TYPE="exfat"
```

I Created a directory:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/usb
```

and tried to mount the USB drive

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdq1 /media/usb/
mount: /media/usb: operation permitted for root only.
```

I used the sudo command but the system still tells me that the operation is permitted for root only.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `sudo -i mount /dev/sdq1 /media/usb/` improve matters?

Comment: @Bib Many thanks for your comment. Unfortunately no, no change in message... :(

Comment: Synology uses also ACL, so thing may be more complex. And I'm not sure sudo of synology is a real sudo. -- In any case: do backups of Synology. For one: you must do it because everybody does backups, but symology command line is particularly weird and it is asy to break thing in a very bad way. -- I think symology do an automount, and probably it is configurable in the control center.